# How do you turn on two player setting in Fruit Ninja?

Tags: fruit-ninja

Does anyone know how to turn on the 2-player setting in Fruit Ninja? I have looked in game center and in extras in the game.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like they removed multiplayer for the time being due to some critical bugs.
https://support.halfbrick.com/hc/en-us/articles/200747434-Missing-Multiplayer